# Ada: Difficulties with generics, incomplete types and self-referencing structures

Tags: generics, package, ada

It's simple in Ada to do that:

```
type ITEM_RECORD;
type ITEM_ACCESS is access ITEM_RECORD;
type ITEM_RECORD Is
record
   ITEM: item_type;
   Next: item_access;
   Pred: item_access;
end record;
```

Easy, right ? Now how do I do if I want to ITEM_ACCESS to be a smart/safe pointers, declared in a generic package ? I intuitively do that, if only it worked:

```
type ITEM_access;
type Item_Record is record
  Item : Item_Type;
  Next : Item_Access;
  Pred : Item_Access;
end record;
type pointers_on_record is access Item_record;
package pointers_p is new pointers(Item_Record, pointers_on_record);
type item_access is new pointers_p.Pointer_Type;
```

the generic's specifications are these:

```
generic
   type Item_Type(<>) is limited private;
   type Access_Type is access Item_Type;
package Pointers is
   type Pointer_Type is private;
```

I haven't figured out how to do it.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you creating a doubly linked list? Why? What is wrong with Ada.Containers.Doubly_Linked_Lists?

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do it with a smart pointer, your smart pointer *must* use an incomplete type.  Because of that, you'll further have to supply a finalization procedure that deletes the access variable (and of course the access type).  This of course also means that your allocation function needs to take an access type instead of a variable.  Finally, you'll absolutely *need* to use weak pointers to break the cyclical references generated by reference counted smart pointers.

```
generic
   type Item_Type(<>);
   type Item_Access is access Item_Type;
   with procedure Finalize(Ref : in out Item_Access);
package Pointers is
   function Make(Ref : not null Item_Access) return Smart_Pointer;
   -- other stuff
end Pointers;
```

Then you can do something like:

```
   type Node_Impl;
   type Node_Access is access Node_Impl;
   procedure Finalize(Ref : in out Node_Access);

   package Ptrs is new Pointers(Node_Impl,Node_Access,Finalize);

   subtype Node is Ptrs.Smart_Pointer;
   subtype Weak_Node is Ptrs.Weak_Pointer;

   type Node_Impl is record
      Value : Some_Type;
      Next : Node;
      Prev : Weak_Node;
   end record;
```

Here is a sample specification that I used to make an AVL tree with smart pointers.  I don't have a linked list example handy.

```
package Trees is
   type Node;
   type Node_Access is access Node;
   procedure Finalize(Memory : in out Node_Access);

   package Node_Smart_Access is new Smart_Access
      (Item_Type        => Node,
       Item_Access      => Node_Access,
       Finalize         => Finalize,
       Atomic_Increment => True);

   type Node is record
      Value  : Integer := 0;
      Height : Integer := 1;
      Parent : Node_Smart_Access.Weak_Access;
      Left   : Node_Smart_Access.Shared_Access;
      Right  : Node_Smart_Access.Shared_Access;
   end record;

   type Tree is tagged record
      Root : Node_Smart_Access.Shared_Access;
   end record;

end Trees;
```

My smart pointer specification was:

```
generic
   type Item_Type(<>);
   type Item_Access is access Item_Type;
   with procedure Finalize(Memory : in out Item_Access);
   Atomic_Increment : Boolean := True;
package Smart_Access is

   type Shared_Access is new Ada.Finalization.Controlled with private;
   type Weak_Access is new Ada.Finalization.Controlled with private;

   -- more stuff

   package Make is
      function Shared_Access
         (Source : in not null Item_Access)
          return Smart_Access.Shared_Access;
      -- more stuff
   end Make;
private
   -- implementation
end Smart_Access;
```

It's cumbersome, but if you want to make self referential types using smart pointers in Ada, it will need to be.  Also note that if you use incomplete types in your specification of your smart pointer, some versions of GNAT have compiler bugs with the Implicit_Dereference aspect.  They will cause a compiler crash when you compile if the version you use has the bug.

Comment: Splendid. I'm starting to grasp what incomplete generic parameters are used for. Indeed, the client might instanciate it with a limited indefinite type, since any type excluding incompletes, can be used with Unchecked_deallocation. Your exemple works because access types have always the same size (wait... isn't it false, technically ? Depending on the type, boundaries can be stored into the pointer right ? How does the generic copes with this fact ?

Comment: The example will work for any type.  The compiler doesn't need to know the size of the access type until the package is instantiated, which it knows by then.  You are correct that access types can have different sizes, but in the case of a generic formal, it doesn't care about the actual size until instantiation (which, as I stated, it knows by then).  The compiler isn't going to try and build any types until then.

Answer (score 6):

The structure you want to create is not possible because of cyclic dependencies. Think about it:

The generic package defines a pointer. The structure and implementation of the `Pointer_Type` (possibly) depends on the generic parameter `Item_Type` (this is not necessarily true, but if it was not, there would be no need to have `Item_Type` as a generic parameter). Now the `Item_Type` in your instantiation of the generic package contains two smart pointers from the generic package, and thus, depends on the structure of the `Pointer_Type`. That's a classical chicken-or-the-egg problem.

So the solution is to change the design of your types. Let me give you some pointers (no pun intended):

It looks like you are implementing a doubly-linked list. Mind that using smart pointers that implement reference counting is a grave mistake because of the cyclic nature of the list. Nothing will ever get deallocated if your list has at least two items, because they are always pointing to each other. So unless your smart pointers are doing cycle detection (which wouldn't be possible based on your specifications), you cannot use smart 
pointers the way you want to.

A possible solution would be to have smart pointers to the `Item_Type`, not the records. You will need to deallocate the records manually, but you need to do that anyway as explained above.

A different solution would be to have a global reference counter for the whole list. Create an opaque list type that provides accessor and iterator subroutines for the list, which hands out smart pointers to the items. The smart pointers increase and decrease the reference count on the whole list, and once the last reference to the list vanishes, the whole list will be deallocated. So the list exists as long as at least one reference to something in it exists. This solution would require you to implement the reference counting yourself, since it is specialised for the list structure.

And finally, you can of course use `Ada.Containers.Doubly_Linked_Lists`, like Jeffrey suggested. You can put smart pointers to your `Item_Type` in there, as I suggested in my first solution.

Comment: So, as expected, the solution is ... you can't. Somehow it doesn't surprise me :-D. Your main point is that it's a design mistake to put smart pointers here. That convinced me. I haven't used standard containers because it's a book exercise where you are told to write them containers ;-) I merely wanted to see exactly where I was wrong.

Comment: I didn't know either the very design for smart pointers would change depending on the data structure it's used in. But it makes sense, obviously.